# ggplot2 dataframe structure bar plot with errorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I got a dataset with 10 measures for 14 subjects, I would like to make a bar plot with the mean score for each subject and errorbars (confidens intervals) in ggplot2. But I'm not sure how to shape the data in order to be able to make such a plot.

any pointers or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` needs data in a long format. Meaning that every data point has to be on a different row. You want to calculate averages and CIs for 14 subjects. Therefore you should have a data.frame with Subject, average and CI columns and 14 rows. Here is an example for two subjects:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Subject = c(rep("Sub1", 10), rep("Sub2", 10)),
Measure = rep(paste0("Meas", 1:10),2),
Value = rnorm(20,15,3)) 

library(plyr)
se <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
dat.new <- ddply(dat, .(Subject), summarize, mean = mean(Value), 
CI = qnorm(0.975)*se(Value))

dat.new
# Data format for ggplot
#  Subject     mean       CI
#1    Sub1 15.39661 1.686627
#2    Sub2 15.74653 1.974250

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat.new, aes(x = Subject, y = mean, ymin = mean, ymax = mean + CI)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") + geom_errorbar(width=0.25)
```

[image]

See [ggplot2 doc's](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/), other questions about [ggplot2 bar plots](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=barplot%20ggplot), and [error bars](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=error%20bar%20ggplot) for more information.

Comment: Nice that this was helpful. Next time prepare an example of your data and define your question a bit better. People here like concrete questions, and you're likely to get a better answer in that way too.